# Questions asking for help finding a suitable font

Tags: discussion

Is it acceptable to ask for help finding a suitable font on this site?

On the stacks that I'm used to, a question like this would almost certainly be considered too broad, or primarily opinion based, but here we have an actual [font-recommendation](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/font-recommendation) tag and the tag excerpt for the [fonts](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fonts) tag reads:

> Questions about matching fonts, using fonts together, manipulating fonts, **font selection and font purchase** and usage rights. Please use a more specific tag if available.

Which seems like the answer to my question, but questions tagged [font-recommendation](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/font-recommendation) don't seem very successful from a cursory glance and I worry I might be seeing what I want to see, especially as the question I want to ask is ... well, pretty opinion based.

---

To make things clear, this is the question I want to ask:

> I'm looking for an Oriya font with full support for the traditional consonant-vowel ligatures and consonant conjuncts.
>
> For example, if we go to [the Wikipedia page on the Oriya/Odia alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odia_alphabet#Dependent_vowels), we find:
>
> > Vowel diacritics may be more or less fused with the consonants, though in modern printing such ligatures have become less common.
>
> And beneath this a table showing all of the consonant-vowel combinations in Oriya, including many irregular ones such as *ki*:
>
> [image]
>
> And *tu*:
>
> [image]
>
> You can also see from [the Omniglot article](http://www.omniglot.com/writing/oriya.htm) (and the Wikipedia one, too, if your font supports them) that Oriya has a very wide range of possible ligatures.
>
> I am looking for an Oriya font which is capable of rendering all of the consonant-vowel ligatures in the Wikipedia article, all of the consonant-consonant ligatures in the Omniglot article, and every base character in the Oriya Unicode block (U+0B00-U+0B7F).
>
> I have tried a number of fonts, including Utkal, FreeSerif and Nirmala UI. All three fonts are attractive options - Nirmala UI especially so. Nirmala UI is also the font used in the Omniglot article and obviously has support for all of the conjunct consonants in that article, but where they all fall down is that none of them support the ligatures of consonant and vowel diacritics shown on the Wikipedia article, e.g. from Nirmala UI:
>
> [image]
>
> Although Nirmala UI does at least have a ligature for *tu* but it is not in the traditional style.
>
> The font used in the images on the Wikipedia article, I happen to know, is e-Oriya OT. I was once the proud user of this very font, but it is no longer to be found online (it used to be available from the University of Hamburg) and I lost my copy when my old laptop went kaput.

Answer (score 8):

By the standard Stack guidelines, these sorts of questions are great *if* the Stack fielding them has a user base with the discipline to keep their answers experience-based.

It's easy to ask questions that are artificially broad, either because querents want to make their questions more useful to others or because they haven't considered how to articulate their situation. This leads to answers which are too vague and general to be much use to anyone, hence the close reason.

The way around this is for answers to be drawn from experience and explain the reasoning behind why they're good answers--and that means [making sure our questions are designed to elicit those sorts of answers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/).

There's a trick to this which actually gets better answers: we can describe our problems rather than asking for the specific tool we think will solve it. It seems obvious that a font problem needs a font solution, and if that's the case then we'll get font answers. But if a font problem can be solved some other way, asking about the *problem* leaves space for creative answers we couldn't have imagined.

So we should try to ask font request questions by describing the problem specifically enough that they can be answered with a structure like this: "In a situation similar to yours, I (or someone I know, someone who wrote an article, etc) did this particular thing. Here's how it worked for me and why I think it'll work for you." Your question looks to me like it fits that bill pretty nicely.

Comment: Yes leading asnwers are bad, but alas way too common.

Comment: Thank you very much, I shall try my luck!